# Chef, File transfer from one node to another

Tags: file, chef-infra

My objective is to transfer file from one node server to another node server using Chef. I want to know how can I do it?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Manish Mehra

Comment: Why don't you package the file as part of your cookbook and use the "cookbook_file" resource in your chef recipe? Other options are the "remote_file" resource.

Answer (score 5):

Chef doesn't do file transfers like this, but it can run commands so it can do whatever you would normally do by hand. You could use Chef to deploy SSH keys and authorization files, and then use scp or sftp for the actual file transfer. You could also setup rsync in daemon mode and use that.

Comment: Thanks. Can I import file from my Chef Node(Client) to my workstation through Chef?

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question. Maybe post it as a new question?